# Does AVAudioRecorder affect my recording?

Tags: swift, avfoundation, core-audio

The question is, if AVAudioRecorder still performs tasks like level adjustment for the recording in the background? Or are there filters in the microphone that can be turned off?
Preferably I would like to use an unprocessed microphone to do a microphone calibration. Is AVFoundation my right choice here, or do I have to read up on Core Audio.

Comment: Consider https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/mode/1616608-measurement

Comment: Oh wow, life can be so easy! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@matt showed the answer in the comment-section:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/mode/1616608-measurement